# Variable importance in decision tree by Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I made my decision tree like below

```
Act_rf <- train(Activity ~ Country + Threat + Target.Section + Author, data = CT1, method = "ranger",trControl = myCont)
```

and then try to obtain my variable importance by using varImp(Act_rf) but then I got the following error. Why is that? and how can I solve it.

```
 ranger variable importance

only 20 most important variables shown (out of 665)

 Overall
374     NaN
370     NaN
247     NaN
574     NaN
316     NaN
149     NaN
593     NaN
420     NaN
386     NaN
104     NaN
462     NaN
288     NaN
32      NaN
342     NaN
552     NaN
90      NaN
292     NaN
512     NaN
322     NaN
52      NaN
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In FUN(newX[, i], ...) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
...
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find by any chance the solution?